# Jenkins ajax calls are using the wrong port

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, jenkins

I installed jenkins, and wanted to change the default port from 8080 to 443. I've got that working, but when going to the Jenkins settings, the system is complaining that the reverse proxy is not configured correctly, and when I take a look, I see that jenkins is trying to call urls on the 8080 port through ajax, which obviously result in a 404

I am using apache, and this is in the config I used.

```
ServerName jenkins.mydomain.com
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/jenkins.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/jenkins.mydomain.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

ProxyRequests     Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
<Proxy http://localhost:8080*>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass         /  http://localhost:8080/ nocanon
ProxyPassReverse  /  http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse  /  http://jenkins.mydomain.com
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
```

Anyone a clue on what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is typically happens because you haven't set your Jenkins URL in the global Jenkins configuration.  The value for "Jenkins URL" in the Jenkins configuration should match the URL that your users enter in their browser's URL bar to visit the web UI - in the example you gave, the value would be `https://jenkins.mydomain.com`.

Jenkins prepends the value of "Jenkins URL" to all AJAX calls.  If the Jenkins URL is not set, it defaults to something along the lines of `http://${hostname}:${port}`, where `hostname` is the hostname of the system Jenkins is running on and `port` is the port Jenkins is running on (8080 in your case).

[Similar answer on Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11335385/1824868)